# Conversion overflows when divide decimal number

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, overflow, division

There is a property which is decimal I want to divide that on 1,000,000 to change the size of number to shorten one, I declare a variable which is decimal too. when I divide, it raises "conversion overflow"
my code like bellow :
PrmSales  and Amt  are both decimal,

```
   var amt = (from p in db.FactTotalAmount
                    group p by p.FromDate  into g
             select new outputList
                   {
                  Amt= (g.Sum(x => x.PrmSales)/1000000)
                   }
```

Comment: What is the type of `PrmSales`?

Comment: decimal . when I add /1000000 it raise error

Comment: absolutely right .

Comment: What precision does `PrmSales` have? .Net precision might be not that ... precise ... as your databases precision on that column.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code that did work and the code that didn't?

Comment: you were right data type of database is money and data type in code is decimal because of deferent precision in two side it raise error . thank you very much your guidance is very help full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is for type of the field in database that is smaller than the type of property in coding because of that I receive that Error.
thank you nilsk !